# what is the return value of numpy mean()?

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio

I found this problem when calculating array from rasters:

```
with rasterio.open(file) as ds:   
    arr3d=ds.read()
    arr3d=np.ma.masked_where(arr3d==-32768,arr3d,False)
    list=[]
    for i in range(0,24):
        tmean=arr3d[i,:,:].mean()  
        list.append(tmean)
```

I just wanted to get the list containing 24 mean values, but this code returned the list including each layer of arr3d, its mask layer and mean values.

```
 len(list)=72
```

But when I tried `arr3d[i,:,:].mean()`, just retruned a mean value without any array. 
What is the differce between `arr.mean()` and `np.mean(arr)`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to read the question; what do you mean by "`arr3d[i,:,:].mean()` just returned a mean value without any array"? The mean value is exactly what this function should return. Regarding the difference between `arr.mean()` and `np.mean(arr)` there should not be any difference. [First thing the latter does is trying to call the former if `arr` is a masked array](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2882).

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the discrepancy or unexpected behavior?

Comment: I just tried again. It's OK. Both of `arr.mean()` and `np.mean(arr)` return same list with 24 elements in this loop. It is weird that `arr.mean()` return 72 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.mean()` returns either: (1) a single value, if the mean is taken along the flattened array or the array is 1-dimensional, or (2) an array of values that has the mean along each of those axes. Because this is confusing, I recommend always explicitly passing the `axis` parameter to the `np.mean()` function. If you don't pass an axis, it takes the mean of the flattened array. Same is true for the `.mean()` function - they are in reality the same function.

I suggest explicitly passing the axis along which you want to compute the mean:

```
with rio.open(file) as ds:   
    arr3d=ds.read()
    arr3d=np.ma.masked_where(arr3d==-32768,arr3d,False)
    means = np.mean(arr3d, axis=0)
```

Then `means` will always have the same number of elements as in the first axis of `arr3d`. You are currently accomplishing this by manually iterating over 24 elements, but you can remove this step.